# Handling database connection exceptions with Linq to SQL and Rx

Tags: linq-to-sql, system.reactive

I am trying learn how to best use the Reactive Extensions library and have set up simple test WPF application to view a logging database table. In a ViewModel class I am populating an `ObservableCollection` with the first 100 log entries from a Linq to Sql `DataContext` and I'm trying to use Rx to keep the UI responsive.

The following snippet works unless the database is unavailable at which point the app throws an exception and crashes. Where would be the best place to handle database connection exceptions and why are they not handled by the `OnError` method of the Observer?

```
ObservableCollection<LogEntry> _logEntries = new ObservableCollection<LogEntry>();

DataContext dataContext = new DataContext( "connection string" );

(from e in dataContext.LogEntries
    select e).Take( 100 ).ToObservable()
    .SubscribeOn( Scheduler.ThreadPool )
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .Subscribe( _logEntries.Add, ex => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( ex.ToString() ) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead of ToObservable:

```
public static IObservable<T> SafeToObservable(this IEnumerable<T> This)
{
    return Observable.Create(subj => {
        try {
            foreach(var v in This) {
                subj.OnNext(v);
            }
            subj.OnCompleted();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            subj.OnError(ex);
        }

        return Disposable.Empty;
    });
}
```

In general though, this isn't a great use of Rx since the data source isn't very easy to Rx'ify - in fact, the code will execute most of the work on the UI thread, send it out to random worker threads, then send it back (i.e. completely wasted work). Task + Dispatcher.BeginInvoke might suit you better here.

Comment: Thanks Paul something like that should help, I was hoping there was some existing mechanism for handling errors during the Observable creation. The example I gave is a really cut down version just to illustrate the problem. The actual data retrieval includes some Interval polling and access to external resources (a bit more Rx'y).

Comment: At which point are exceptions normally passed to the OnError method?

Comment: If an exception that happens while enumerating a sequence it will be passed through to OnError. The exception you are seeing, db connection failed, is caused when GetEnumerator is called. Logically this is outside the sequence (because there isn’t even one) and the exception is not handled by Rx. My suggestion would be to wrap your code in a try/catch to separate the concepts enumerating through data and attempting to get data to enumerate.